# Getting first character of string in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am trying to write a program that compares single characters, but it says the buffer is not equal to 'S' even though I gave one as input, I know there comes a new-line and terminating sign after the input string but isn't [.buffer] just supposed to give the first character of the string?

```
section .text
    global main

main:
    jmp start_promt

start_promt:
section .data
    .promt       db      "Choose one of the following instructions: (S)tart, (Q)uit",10,0
    .promtLen    equ     $-.promt-1   ; memory address of begin of this instruction minus memory address of begin of promt gives length of promt  
    .bufsize     dq      100
section .bss
    .buffer resd 100
section .text
    mov     rax, 1          ; rax <- 0 (syscall number for 'write')
    mov     rdi, 1          ; rdi <- 0 (stdout file descriptor)
    mov     rsi, .promt      ; address of prompt message
    mov     rdx, .promtLen   ; size of promt message
    syscall                 ; execute  write(1, promt, promtLen)

    xor rax, rax            ; rax <- 0 (syscall number for 'read')
    xor rdi, rdi            ; rdi <- 0 (stdin file descriptor)
    mov rsi, .buffer         ; rsi <- address of the buffer.  lea rsi, [rel buffer]
    mov rdx, [.bufsize]        ; rdx <- size of the buffer
    syscall                 ; execute  read(0, buffer, BUFSIZE)

    mov rdx, [.buffer]

    cmp rdx, 'S'
    je start_game 

    cmp rdx, 'Q'
    je quit


    jmp start_promt

start_game:
; loop for user-instructions
; if done
    ;jmp start_promt

quit: 
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Comment: Why do you think you need `-1` in `$-.promt-1`?

Comment: To remove the termination character

Comment: I see way on the right side. Is there any need to create `.promt` with the nul-terminating character since you are using `write` for output? Let me look further.

Comment: I saw this in a book, I dont actually write the termination sign since I write length - 1

Comment: You're fine there -- your problem is *Register Size*. You don't put a byte in `rdx`, you put 1-byte in `dl`, e.g. `mov dl, [.buffer]` and then `cmp dl, 'S'` and `cmp dl, 'Q'` (you know `dl` byte register, `dx` 2-bytes, `edx` 4-bytes, and finally `rdx` 8-bytes.) That said, unless you are using `.promt` as a nul-terminated string, there is no reason to make it one.the `write` syscall doesn't need it, and from what you posted, nothing else does either. Up to you, just no need for it.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a solid answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from the comment above, you comparison is failing because you are attempting to compare a single byte `'S'` or `'Q'` against an 8-byte register. That won't work. `rdx` has 7 other bytes that will not be `'S'` or `'Q'` and the test will fail every time.

Stepping each instruction in `gdb` makes it easy to see. Run `gdb yourexecutable`, then `break _start` to create a breakpoint at the program start. (for convenience display the current command being executed by setting `display/i $pc`) Now just use `si` to step-instruction through your code. When you get to your data entry and comparison, examine the contents of both `.buffer` and `rdx`, e.g.

```
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x4000e5 <start_promt+51>:   syscall
(gdb)
SoooRO
0x00000000004000e7 in start_promt ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x4000e7 <start_promt+53>:   mov    0x600150,%rdx
(gdb) x/6c 0x600150
0x600150:       83 'S'  111 'o' 111 'o' 111 'o' 82 'R'  79 'O'
(gdb) si
0x00000000004000ef in start_promt ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x4000ef <start_promt+61>:   cmp    $0x53,%rdx
(gdb) info reg rdx
rdx            0xa4f526f6f6f53     2901965242593107
```

Above you can see `"SoooRO"` was entered at the prompt just to fill a few extra characters. The address of `.buffer` is `0x600150` so you can check the contents of buffer with `x/6c 0x600150` (examine 6-characters from buffer) and you see:

```
0x600150:       83 'S'  111 'o' 111 'o' 111 'o' 82 'R'  79 'O'
```

All good -- so why did the compare fail? That is shown in the debug as well:

```
=> 0x4000ef <start_promt+61>:   cmp    $0x53,%rdx
(gdb) info reg rdx
rdx            0xa4f526f6f6f53     2901965242593107
```

Where you see the register holds `0xa4f526f6f6f53` (the last byte is ASCII `0x53` - `'S'`).

So how to fix this? Use the correct register to store a byte. `dl` is the one-byte register, `dx` is a two-byte register, `edx` is a four-byte register and `rdx` is an eight-byte register. So moving the first character to `dl` and then comparing with `dl` will make the single-character comparison you are looking for, e.g.

```
    mov dl, [.buffer]

    cmp dl, 'S'
    je start_game 

    cmp dl, 'Q'
    je quit
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Can I also do, mov rdx, [.buffer], cmp dl, 'S'?

Comment: You can, but I find it more readable to use the proper size register in all places. You are dereferencing `.buffer`, e.g. `[.buffer]` and when you dereference a pointer you get the first element of the type pointed-to. In the case of a character-string (pointer to char), you get a single byte. Keeping your register size consistent not only helps you follow the flow, but also anyone who has to maintain the code you have written later.

Comment: @Vexea: Yes, since your `.buffer` is 100 x 4 bytes long, an 8-byte load from the start of it can't cross into an unmapped page and segfault.  And it's aligned by at least 8 so your 8-byte load is naturally aligned and won't have any performance downside e.g. from being split across two cache lines.  Of course, it's pointlessly inefficient to use an instruction that needs a REX prefix to specify 8-byte operand-size instead of `mov edx, [.buffer]`, which would actually be the most efficient way in terms of code-size, equal to `movzx edx, byte [.buffer]` which is the normal way to load a byte.

Comment: @Vexea: Of course, for code-size you could do `cmp byte [.buffer], 'S'`, but if you're doing other compares on the byte you should load it into a reg once.  `cmp` with a RIP-relative addressing mode and an immediate can't micro-fuse into a single uop, and IIRC can't macro-fuse the following jcc instruction either.  (`mov dl, [.buffer]` has the downside of a false dependency on the old value of RDX, just merging a new low byte into it.  If you don't specifically want that, use `movzx`.  Also use `default rel` somewhere in your source because NASM defaults to absolute addressing.)